# Why is (date1, date2) a valid expression in javascript?

Tags: javascript, syntax

I know, weird question. I accidentally pasted an expression in the the Chrome developer tools console but copied it without the function call so instead of:

```
dayDiff(date1, date2)
```

I just ran

```
(date1, date2)
```

with the variables in parenthesis separated by a comma, which simply returns the value of date2. I'm trying to understand what the engine is interpreting this expression as. I would've expected this to be a syntax error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator). It simply evaluates both arguments and returns the RHS value.

Comment: It *is* a comma operator by why link to the C++ docs on it, instead of any JS sources?

Comment: Ah, got it. I wasn't aware of that (in JS, or C++), but my mind went to crazier possibilities. Thanks.

Comment: @vlaz JS stems from the C family, so why not?

Comment: Because 1. there are [already JS docs for this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) 2. Even though it comes from C (which is not 100% true, as it also has roots in functional programming, namely Schema) the documentation there doesn't mean it's correct for JS. In fact, according to the C++ reference, you can override a comma operator, which is certainly not possible for JS. 3. It suggests to newcomers that C++ reference is valid for anything JS related. 4. You didn't offer any reason *for* using this source.